# Localization at a prime ideal and quotient module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Problem.

> Let $A$ be a commutative ring with 1, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. If $p$ is a prime ideal of $A$, prove that $M/pM$ is non zero if and only if the localization $M_p$is non zero.

I think it's true..

Let $S$ be a $A-p$ , then if $M_p$ is zero, there exist some $s$ in $A-p$
such that given $x$ in M, $sx$=$0$. so the left looks trivial

but if we can find a module s.t $M_0$=$0$ (localization at zero ideal)

then we can talk $M$ is nonzero

Help me

Answer (score 4):

The statement that they are equivalent is false, but one direction is true. I provide a proof of this direction and a counterexample to the other direction below. Fix a commutative ring $A$ with unit, a finitely generated $A$-module $M$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $A$.

> Claim. $M/\mathfrak{p}M=0 \implies M_\mathfrak{p}=0.$

*Proof.* If $M/\mathfrak{p}M=0$ then $M=\mathfrak{p}M.$ Localising this expression at $\mathfrak{p}$ we get $M_\mathfrak{p}=(\mathfrak{p}M)_\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}M_\mathfrak{p}.$ But now this is all happening as $A_\mathfrak{p}$-modules, which is a local ring with unique maximal ideal, and hence Jacobson radical, $\mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}$. Thus, by Nakayama's Lemma, we have that $M_\mathfrak{p}=0$ as $M_\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}_\mathfrak{p}M$ and this finishes the proof. $\square$

Now for the counterexample to the converse, which states that if $M/\mathfrak{p}M\neq0$ then $M_\mathfrak{p}\neq 0$ (equivalently, $M_\mathfrak{p}=0 \implies M/\mathfrak{p}M=0$). Let $A := \mathbb{Z}, M := \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(0).$ Thus, we have $\mathfrak{p}M=(0)\cdot \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=0,$ so $M/\mathfrak{p}M=M/0=M\neq 0.$

Now we will show that $M_\mathfrak{p}=0$. We have a short exact sequence $$ 0\to 2\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to M\to 0$$ of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Localisation is exact so, in particular, localising at $\mathfrak{p}=(0)$ is exact. Therefore, we get the following exact sequence: $$ 0\to (2\mathbb{Z})_{(0)}\to\mathbb{Z}_{(0)}\to M_\mathfrak{p}\to 0.$$

But localising at $\mathfrak{p}=0$ is the same as inverting all non-zero elements of $\mathbb{Z}$, so $\mathbb{Z}_{(0)}=\mathbb{Q}$ and $(2\mathbb{Z})_{(0)}=\mathbb{Q}$, where the localisation of the inclusion $2\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ becomes an isomorphism. (Since $\mathbb{Z}_{(0)}=\mathbb{Q}$, it has just two submodules -- $0$ and itself -- so the image of this inclusion must be the whole of $\mathbb{Q}$ since $(2\mathbb{Z})_{(0)}\neq0$ and the localisation of the inclusion is still an inclusion.)

Hence, the short exact sequence obtained after the localisation tells us that $M_\mathfrak{p}=0$. (The idea is that localising at $(0)$ inverts $2$ in $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is very bad as 2 is a zero-divisor!)